# Images looking on different locations in the device and the desktop

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx framework to develop my first android game but the problem here is when i run the game on desktop images looks big and on the correct location but when i run it on the device it looks a little bit small and on the different location. I am using ScreenViewport, my main concern is about the location of the images.

Comment: add your code if you want some help

Comment: Don't use `ScreenViewport`. For most games you want to use `ExtendViewport`, so that size and location will appear the same everywhere. See [viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) for more info.